# How to involve table index in filtering of 3 conditions?

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

I have table with 30 mln records and I want to get data by some query very fast. I have these fields: id (int), field1 (int), field2 (int), field3 (int). So I want to query data by this condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE field3 = 1 
AND (field1 < field2 OR field2 < 0) 
LIMIT 1
```

Query plan I got

```
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from mytable mt where (mt.field1 < mt.field2 OR mt.field2 < 0) and mt.field3 = 1 limit 1;
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.37 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=525.050..525.051 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=245 read=35166
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable mt  (cost=0.00..359373.97 rows=983846 width=13) (actual time=525.048..525.048 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: ((field3 = 1) AND ((field1 < field2) OR (field2 < 0)))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 4006175
         Buffers: shared hit=245 read=35166
 Planning time: 0.163 ms
 Execution time: 525.077 ms
```

I have index set on field3 but it used by postgres only with

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE field3 = 1 
LIMIT 1
```

I tried to set index on fields (field3, field1, field2), then on the (field3, field2, field1), but it only works without `field1 < field2`.

Then I tried to set index only for condition `field1 < field2`. Indexes (field1, field2) and (field2, field1) don't work too.

What index do I need to use it with condition `field1 < field2`?

Update.
I add partial index by condition

```
CREATE INDEX idx_mytable_condition_1 ON mytable (field3) WHERE (field1 < field2 OR field2 < 0);
```

but anyway there's no using index, only seq scan

```
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from mytable mt where mt.field3 = 1 and (mt.field1 < mt.field2 OR mt.field2 < 0) limit 1;
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.37 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=492.787..492.787 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=277 read=35134
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable mt  (cost=0.00..359373.97 rows=983846 width=37) (actual time=492.785..492.785 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: ((field3 = 1) AND ((field1 < field2) OR (field2 < 0)))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 4006175
         Buffers: shared hit=277 read=35134
 Planning time: 0.110 ms
 Execution time: 492.806 ms
```

Comment: The first query should make use of the index on field3. Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for the first query generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not a just a plain `explain`). [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: If that is a condition you use very often, a partial index should help: `create index on the_table (column3) where (column1 < column2 or column2 < 0);`

Comment: I added query plan

Comment: partial index doesn't work too

Comment: I did `ANALYZE mytable`, but all is the same. I did mistake, my table has 13 mln rows, but I think than 4 mln rows removed because they have `field3 <> 1`. If I do `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field3 = 2 AND (field1 < field2 OR field2 < 0)` it remove 9711408 rows.

Comment: I noticed that if I do the same query with the same field3 value at second and more times it works very fast and removes only 1000 rows. But if I change field3 value query goes slow again. Is this caching? Maybe I can exploit this feature? Which keywords can I google it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The estimated number of rows for the seq scan are without the limit being applied, and the actual values reflect the limit being applied, so in this case that discrepancy is not proof of poor estimates.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, because it stops filtering rows once the limit is satisfied.  So it filters out 4,000,000 rows before finding the first one that meets the criteria.  He said there are 30 and/or 13 mln rows, and there is no evidence to the contrary here in that plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with correlations of the expressions.  The cases where `field3 = 1` are selectively depleted of cases where `((field1 < field2) OR (field2 < 0))`.  PostgreSQL thinks that those are independent, but they aren't.  So it thinks you will very quickly find a qualifying row by doing a seq scan.  But instead it had to dig through 4 million before finding the first one.

A quirk of PostgreSQL is that it collects special statistics on functional indexes, but not on plain partial indexes.  So if you add a dummy function to your partial index, you may get a better plan:

```
create index on mytable (abs(field3)) WHERE (field1 < field2 OR field2 < 0);
```

And then your query would have to use `abs(field3)=1` in the condition.  Of course you can only do that if field3 is never negative, otherwise pick some other dummy function to use.

Comment: What about using [`create statistics`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createstatistics.html) instead?

Comment: Thanks, @jjanes, this is first answer that at least works

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm using 9.6, but thanks for advise.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You can't `create statistics` on expressions, only actual columns.  And when I materialized the expression `(field1 < field2 OR field2 < 0)` into a single bool column and then gathered statistics jointly on (field3, new_column) it actually got worse rather than better.  I don't know why, I put it onto my list of things to look into...eventually.

Comment: I was thinking about statistics on (only) the three columns, as then Postgres "knows" the dependency between them.

Comment: I don't think the joint statistics are general enough that it would do a good job of estimating "A and (B<C or C<0)".  I think both the "or", and the between-column inequality "B<C", would defeat it.